# How do I sort in XSL based on another list that have been sorted?

Tags: xml, xslt

I wonder if there is a way to either set some kind of relation between two lists in xsl or 
if I can somehow use the sort that i've done on one list and apply that on to another list.
Since i have two XML lists with translations, I want to keep the words on the same line even though I've sorted one side alphabetically.

```xml
<!-- <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" />
 ^ The code above is only to show the xslt version ^ -->

<ul>
            <h1><xsl:value-of select="$first/Lexicon/Title"/></h1>
            <xsl:for-each select="$first/Lexicon/Words/Word">
              <xsl:sort select="."/>
              <li>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
              </li>
            </xsl:for-each>

</ul>
<ul>
            <h1><xsl:value-of select="$second/Lexicon/Title"/></h1>
            <xsl:for-each select="$second/Lexicon/Words/Word">
              <li>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
              </li>
            </xsl:for-each>

</ul>
```

The $first and the $second variable refers to two XML document with Words. They both have the same structure.

$first

```xml
<Lexicon>
    <Title> English </Title>
    <Author> SafeSailor </Author>
    <Words>
        <Word> Car </Word>
        <Word> Programming </Word>
        <Word> Write </Word>
        <Word> Run </Word>
        <Word> Drink </Word>
        <Word> Potato </Word>
        <Word> Rowan-berry </Word>
        <Word> Weight </Word>
        <Word> Group </Word>
        <Word> People </Word>
    </Words>
</Lexicon>
```

Comment: Are you simply trying to avoid duplicate code here, and have one block of code that could operate on either list? Thanks!

Comment: @TimC That would be great too. But I don't think that is possible since one list should be sorted alphabetically and the other list just kind of have to apply to the same kind of sort. Meaning that if I have the word "Car", that means "Bil" in swedish, then i want them on the same line

Comment: So where is the sorting done so far? Your XSLT code does not show any sorting attempt. Also please add information about the XSLT version you use or the XSLT processor you use, as XSLT 2/3 with `xsl:perform-sort` and with functions like `index-of` and `sort` have easier ways to sort and search for an index.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, I just added that. Thank you for pointing it out

Comment: A compact XSLT 3 approach is at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6rewNxW, for XSLT 1 I guess you need to sort and store in a result tree fragment, convert it to a node-set and do a bit of more work than using `index-of`.

Comment: @SafeSailor -- there exists an XSLT 2 (easily convertible to XSLT 1) solution that only performs a single sort. More details below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XSLT 1 you can sort the English version each time and use `xsl:number` to find the original input position and index the second list:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" doctype-system="about:legacy-doctype"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>.NET XSLT Fiddle Example</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="list[lang('en')]">
      <ul>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="word">
              <xsl:sort select="."/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
      </ul>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="word">
      <li>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </li>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="list[not(lang('en'))]">
      <ul>
          <xsl:variable name="non-english-list" select="word"/>
          <xsl:for-each select="../list[lang('en')]/word">
              <xsl:sort select="."/>
              <xsl:variable name="pos">
                  <xsl:number/>
              </xsl:variable>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="$non-english-list[number($pos)]"/>
          </xsl:for-each>
      </ul>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6rewNxW/2

In XSLT 3 you can use `index-of` and `sort`: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6rewNxW

Comment: It looks really good. But how do I tie my $first and $second variable in to this?
```lang-xml
<xsl:variable name="first" select="document(metadata/dictionaries/first)" />
  <xsl:variable name="second" select="document(metadata/dictionaries/second)" />
```

Comment: If there is no attribute or child element allowing you to distinguish the two dictionaries in a match pattern I would suggest to use a mode e.g. the `<xsl:template match="list[lang('en')]">` would be `<xsl:template match="Words">` and the `<xsl:template match="Words" mode="second">` and then of course `<xsl:variable name="non-english-list" select="Word"/>` and `<xsl:for-each select="$first/Lexicon/Words/Word">`.

Comment: And in the root template or where you want to output the two lists you would use `<xsl:apply-templates select="$first/Lexicon/Words"/>` together with `<xsl:apply-templates select="$second/Lexicon/Words" mode="second"/>`. And you will need to duplicate the `match="Word"` for both modes.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is an XSLT 2.0 solution -- it does only a single sort**!

Also, can be easily converted to XSLT 1.0

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vDocEn" select="/"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vDocBG">
   <Lexicon>
    <Title> Български </Title>
    <Author> SafeSailor </Author>
    <Words>
        <Word> Кола </Word>
        <Word> Програмиране </Word>
        <Word> Пиши </Word>
        <Word> Бягай </Word>
        <Word> Пий </Word>
        <Word> Картоф </Word>
        <Word> Калина </Word>
        <Word> Тегло </Word>
        <Word> Група </Word>
        <Word> Хора </Word>
    </Words>
  </Lexicon>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:variable name="vCompositeWords" as="element()*">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="$vDocEn/*/Words" mode="combine">
     <xsl:with-param name="pWords2" select="$vDocBG/*/Words"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$vCompositeWords"/>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$vCompositeWords/@translation"/>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Words" mode="combine">
    <xsl:param name="pWords2" as="element()"/>

    <xsl:for-each select="Word">
      <xsl:sort/>
      <word translation="{$pWords2/Word[position() = count(current()/preceding-sibling::*)+1]}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </word>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="word | @translation">
    <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided document**:

```
<Lexicon>
    <Title> English </Title>
    <Author> SafeSailor </Author>
    <Words>
        <Word> Car </Word>
        <Word> Programming </Word>
        <Word> Write </Word>
        <Word> Run </Word>
        <Word> Drink </Word>
        <Word> Potato </Word>
        <Word> Rowan-berry </Word>
        <Word> Weight </Word>
        <Word> Group </Word>
        <Word> People </Word>
    </Words>
</Lexicon>
```

**The wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<ul>
   <li> Car </li>
   <li> Drink </li>
   <li> Group </li>
   <li> People </li>
   <li> Potato </li>
   <li> Programming </li>
   <li> Rowan-berry </li>
   <li> Run </li>
   <li> Weight </li>
   <li> Write </li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li> Кола </li>
   <li> Пий </li>
   <li> Група </li>
   <li> Хора </li>
   <li> Картоф </li>
   <li> Програмиране </li>
   <li> Калина </li>
   <li> Бягай </li>
   <li> Тегло </li>
   <li> Пиши </li>
</ul>
```